# Compilation error Can't locate Tie/Array/CSV.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I am using [`Tie::Array::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~jberger/Tie-Array-CSV-0.07/lib/Tie/Array/CSV.pm) in my code but I get a compilation error.
I have DWIM perl for windows installed.

Error:

```
Can't locate Tie/Array/CSV.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib
C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .)
```

I tried looking for CSV.pm but it doesn't exist. How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a linux machine you'd use cpan to install Tie::Array::CSV:

```
cpan -i Tie::Array::CSV
```

Comment: Same on Windows, but if you use ActivePerl, I suggest you try `ppm install Tie::Array::CSV` first. (Note that the `-i` is redundant and can be omitted.)